# Bootstrap Button with link does not work on mobile Safari

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an webpage which shows a button:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="index.php?option=com_communityquiz&amp;view=quiz&   amp;Itemid=142">Take a Quiz</a></p>
```

It works in Firefox but does not work on my mobile Safari?

see: [med-quiz.com](http://med-quiz.com)

Any Idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

works fine from over here... I tried it on my iPhone, clicked the button, and went to the URL in your code...